# programmatically force killing another app on iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, terminate

I'm developing two iphone apps suppose - App A and App B and both apps need not run simultaneously due to some reason.

Now my question is - Is it possible for App A to kill App B in iOS programmatically using Swift ?
If yes.. does apple allows it or not ?

As per below apple link...i'm not sure is it possible or not :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill an app by calling the private method `terminateWithSuccess` from `UIApplication`, like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector("terminateWithSuccess")
```

But please, don't do this.

Also, this it's not allowed by Apple.

> Never quit an iOS app programmatically. People tend to interpret this as a crash. If something prevents your app from functioning as intended, you need to tell users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.  [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/StartingStopping.html)

Killing another app from an app that's currently in the background is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: even if apps both apps are from same company ?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. There might be some private APIs that could make this work, but officially there's no way to do this AFAIK. Also, you have to understand that the app that's on the background could get killed by the OS if it's running out of resources so I'd recommend against this pattern.

Answer (score 5):

If both apps have the documented UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key set in their app plist, then only one can be running at a time, since neither can run in the background.  If a user launches one app, the OS will kill the other app.